# Why doesn't Blender's Blackbody node set to 6500K output pure white(before color management)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

Blender internally uses linear color space with Rec. 709 chromaticities and D65 white point([source](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/post_process/color_management.html#opencolorio-configuration)). Doesn't that mean that pure white should match blackbody at 6500K? If so, why is it that if you assign an emission shader with color defined by Blackbody node set to 6500K to some object, render it and sample the color in the render output, it is not pure white before color management is applied?

[image]

Comment: Could it be that this is more suitable for the developers to answer? https://devtalk.blender.org/

Comment: It could... :D Doesn't seem to be off-topic here as well though. Simple question about how Blender works... :D I'll try though.

Comment: As far as I know, 6500 K is in the range of daylight blueish white. Neutral white is around 3500 K to 4500 K (according to lightbulb manufacturers), but can have a slight blue tint as well. So in general below 3500 or 3000 K is "warm" and above it it's "cool", with having a yellow to orange tint for the lower temperatures and a blue tint for the higher temperatures. I'm actually not sure if you really can get a "perfect" neutral white with the temperature, but 6500 K should be in the blue range, not "pure" white.

Comment: My understanding is that human eye is evolved to perceive large part of blackbody radiation as pure white and adjusts depending on the conditions. We see 3000K as pure white if everything around us is lit by that temperature light and we also perceive 6500K, or 5000K or 4500K as pure white if our environment is lit by that light. I thought that 6500K is pure white in the context of sRGB color space or any color space with D65 white point including Blender's internal linear color space. I might be missing something about how exactly 6500K that is supposed to be though.

Comment: Change the values in your question to [6504](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant#:~:text=D65%20values,-Using%20the%20standard&text=Since%20D65%20represents%20white%20light,color%20temperature%20of%206504%20K)?

Comment: Apparently, [we could](https://imgur.com/7YjTyX3), that makes sense. I suspect that's part of the answer. There is a mysterious [example of the color ranges of the Blackbody node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/blackbody.html#examples) in the manual. I suspect the node uses a table of values and 6504 is not part of it.

Comment: No time to continue yesterday... I guess the _Blackbody_ node most likely uses the Planckian locus (which is not linear) which represent actual temperatures of incandescent bodies and their color, standard illuminants like D65 are no real light sources... so this might be a source for discrepancies in white points. The other is: instead of a temperature, just set a color in the _Emission_ node, no matter if (1, 0, 0) or (0, 1, 1) or white (1, 1, 1) - sampling the render will still not give perfect 1.00000 in any of the channels. So the 6504 K white is just as good as "white" (1, 1, 1).

Comment: Oh, but [it does](https://imgur.com/CuUydMN).  [For channels as well](https://imgur.com/E7C1AEk). Clamping might mess with it. There might also be a bug of lights not updating when re-rendering with persistent data enabled in the render settings(4.0.2)(I've experienced some inconsistencies, but did't look too much into it), not sure if its the case with mesh lights.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys My mistake. I use denoising, which messed up the values. I did not expect a face with (1, 1, 1) everywhere to change to something else by denoising. But as I said, the Planckian locus is based on real temperatures of incandescent bodies and does not necessarily exactly match the CCT of D65. To quote from the "Handbook on the Physics and Chemistry of Rare Earths": _"A nonblackbody source is often described by the correlated color temperature (CCT), which is the temperature of a blackbody radiator that **most closely** resembles the color from a source of equal brightness."_